# Is there a way to convert swagger inspector yaml result into php attributes?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-inspector

Swagger inspector is a great tool that create openapi documentation just by giving an URL.

But it creates a yaml file and I would like to get it in PHP attributes because I mostly use PHP attributes in my application.
I'd like to be able to generate it in PHP attributes, or be able to convert the yaml to PHP attributes.

What I get:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: defaultTitle
  description: defaultDescription
  version: '0.1'
servers:
  - url: http://localhost.fr:8002
paths:
  /api/package:
    post:
      description: Auto generated using Swagger Inspector
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                software:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                      package:
                        type: string
                      version:
                        type: string
...
```

What I'd like:

```
<?php

use OpenApi\Attributes as OA;

#[OA\Post(
    path: '/api/package',
    requestBody: new OA\RequestBody(
        description: 'Add a new package',
        required: true,
        content: new OA\MediaType(
            mediaType: 'multipart/form-data',
            schema: new OA\Schema(
                properties: [
                    new OA\Property(
                        property: 'package',
                        type: 'string',
                    ),
                    new OA\Property(
                        property: 'version',
                        type: 'string',
                    ),
                ]
            )
        )
    )
)]
class AddPackage
{
}
```